# Why does the Google Knowledge Graph API not return businesses that I know have a Google Knowledge Panel?

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I am trying to programatically find out whether a given company has a google knowledge panel. for instance, when i search google for the company "Aeronaut Brewing Company", I get a sidebar that displays relevant information about the company. This is called the knowledge panel. Google's knowledge graph api is supposed to return this information, and for aeronaut it does:

https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Aeronaut+Brewing+Company&key=YOUR_API_KEY&limit=10&indent=True

However, I've noticed that plenty of companies who have a knowledge panel do not show up in google knowledge graph api. for instance:

The Affton Chamber of Commerce has a sidebar on google ([link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Affton%20Chamber%20of%20Commerce,%20Affton,%20Missouri&cad=h)), but a google knowledge graph search comes back as only the following JSON (basically it's empty):

https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=affton+chamber+of+commerce&key=YOUR_API_KEY&limit=10&indent=True

```
@context    
@vocab  "http://schema.org/"
goog    "http://schema.googleapis.com/"
EntitySearchResult  "goog:EntitySearchResult"
detailedDescription "goog:detailedDescription"
kg  "http://g.co/kg"
@type   "ItemList"
itemListElement []
```

What's going on? Shouldn't google knowledge graph API contain everything that has a knowledge panel on google??

Answer (score 3):

The MID (machine-generated identifier, also known as Google Knowledge Graph ID) of the Affton Chamber of Commerce is `/g/1hg4ww6pq` ([SERP link](https://g.co/kg/g/1hg4ww6pq)). Unlike the entities that start with `/m/` that originated from Freebase, `/g/` entities are internal to Google and don't tend to be exposed through the Knowledge Graph API.